# Chef-Client Fails intermittently

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to play with Chef Zero on a Windows Machine. This is what i did.

- Installed ChefDK
- Created a cookbook Modified the default recipe to create a local file
- Navigated to .chef folder in the Windows Users folder and gave the following command.

  ```
  chef-client -z -o testcookbook
  ```

When i run this command I get the following error. Can any of you help me to fix this issue? The simple recipe file is pasted at the end.

```
C:\Users\ntusername\.chef>chef-client -z -o testcookbook
WARN:    
WARN: Did not find config file: C:\chef\client.rb,using command line options.    
WARN:
Starting Chef Client, version 12.5.1
Creating a new client identity for mycomputer.domainname using the validator key.
========================================================================
Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "mycomputer.domainname"
========================================================================
Running handlers:    
ERROR: Running exception handlers    
Running handlers complete    
ERROR: Exception handlers complete    
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 01 minutes 08 seconds    
FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to C:/Users/myntusername/.chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::CannotWritePrivateKey: I cannot write your private key to C:\chef\client.pem - check permissions?
```

Recipe:

```
file "c:\mydish.txt" do
    action :create
end
```

Comment: As the error message `C:\chef\client.pem - check permissions?` suggests, you might want to run `chef-client` with administrator user privileges.

Comment: Do you mean _immediately_ instead of _intermittently_ btw.?

Comment: I meant intermittently , because I saw it working 2 times. I followed same steps mentioned above. I ran the chef client from an elevated command prompt, still same result.

Comment: Is there a `c:\chef` directory existing ? There's few reason which can prevent writing the file, permission errors on the directory, or non existing directory...

Comment: There was no directory. So I created that directory. But still it did not work.

Comment: @SecureBlob it's a wild guess but I've seen intermittent behavior from users when they run the chef-client command as local user. The cause was obviously permission issue. Try to right-click and open the console as admin and see if it solves the issue.